# Python program for soccer odds

Tags: python, replace, isnumeric

```
match = input('Enter match? ')
odd1 = input("Enter tip for home: ")
if(not odd1.replace(".","").isnumeric()): 
    print("Sorry home tip is not numeric")
    exit(0)
if(float(odd1)<=1):
    print("Odd cannot be less than one")
    exit(0)
odd2 = input("Enter tip for draw: ")
if(not odd2.replace(".","").isnumeric()):
    print("Sorry draw tip is not numeric")
    exit(0)
if(float(odd2)<=1):
    print("Odd cannot be less than one")
    exit(0)
odd3 = input("Enter tip for away: ")
#isnumberic() is it number
if(not odd3.replace(".","").isnumeric()):
    print("Sorry your tip is not numeric")
    exit(0) 
if(float(odd3)<=1):
    print("Odd cannot be less than one")
    exit(0)

print("Thank you, your odd is: ")
print("Match: ", match)
print("Home: ", odd1)
print("Draw: ", odd2)
print("Away: ", odd3)
```

> Generally replace(val1, val2) method changes old value with a new one which is second argument. Why in this code checks if number is float. If I type float number in odd1 without **replace**, I am getting the message **Sorry home tip is not numeric**?

Comment: It replaces instances of the pattern (first argument) with the empty string `""`, i.e. it removes them.

Comment: Please refer to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for the replace method. Replacing something with nothing is a valid use - an empty string is still a string. You could try it yourself in an interactive session doing, for example, `'abcde'.replace('d', '')` and see what happens.

Comment: It deletes the characters by replacing them with nothing (the empty string).

Comment: Are you trying to test whether the input is a valid representation of a number? Just call `float` and catch the exception if it fails. Ad-hoc solutions like this are almost always wrong, and writing a *correct* ad-hoc solution is very hard to get right or to demonstrate that it's right.

Comment: For example, your code thinks `1.2.3` is a number and `-1` isn't.

Comment: I can see for example : 'abcde'.replace('d', '') that it will remove d. But in the code above when I input 2.5 in terminal I see 2.5 and not 25 ( which would be removed '.')

Comment: When you do `odd1.replace(".","").isnumeric()` you don't change `odd1` . With `odd1.replace(".","")` you create a new string and then call `isnumeric` on that new string.

Comment: Why is new string necessary?

Answer (score 1):

odd1.replace(".","") means that change every dot in the string odd1 into to nothing (means delete it) generally .replace() is used to search about a char in a string and replace it with another
for example

```
s = "Hello. world"

r = s.replace(".", ",")

print(r)
```

this code replace every dot in the string s with a comma

and then `.isnumeric()` tests if the value of odd1 after replacing is a number or not

Comment: I know this. Thank you. However, I want to figure out why in my program with odds replace is used to accept float numbers . Without replace method , floats are not counted as numbers.